# hittest, removechild,not visible object remain issue,flash ,as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest, removechild

I am trying to remove object called '_pokemon'. It should be removed if it get hit ten times by rain falling down called '_jednaLinia' (means '_oneLine'). I do use this code, and yes it does the job my _pokemon does disappear but it still gets detected on handleColisin function. And Main class still keeps referring to it because I got this error on Pokemon class

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

---

I am quit new to AS3 and tried many simple solution but nothing seems to work how I intend it to.
If possible please answer.

```
 ## some code I think is necessary, not all of it
...
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    private var _pokemon:Pokemon;       
    public function Main():void 
    {   
        _starTimer = new Timer(30); 
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        _starTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, start);

    }
    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);    
        _starTimer.start();
        this.addChild(_pokemon);

    }




...and further...

    private function _pokemonLive(e:Event = null):void
    {           
        decreaseLive--;         
        if (decreaseLive == 0)
        {               
            _pokemon.parent.removeChild( _pokemon );/i think i tried all methods
            _starTimer.stop();
        }
    }
```

And like I mentioned. I got error on Pokemon Class it has got random movement function on it. And it is where the error 1009 shows. If necessary I send more code.

Comment: When do you call _pokemonLive?  Is it an event listener?

Comment: This part of code which activate _pokemonLive is in the privat function which is called with timeEvent listener and is named "start" `code'.................. if ( _pokemon.hitTestObject(_linia[count]) )
       {
       handleCollision(_linia[count]);    _pokemonLive();   
       }

Comment: Look at my answer, it should work, then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'dead' Boolean to your 'Main' Class.

Change

```
private function _pokemonLive(e:Event = null):void
    {           
        decreaseLive--;                       
            _pokemon.parent.removeChild( _pokemon );
            _starTimer.stop();
    }
```

to

```
private function _pokemonLive(e:Event = null):void
    {           
        if(dead == false)
        {     
        decreaseLive --;   
        if (decreaseLive == 0)
        {            
            dead = true;  
            _pokemon.parent.removeChild( _pokemon );/i think i tried all methods
            _starTimer.stop();
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx didn't try this way. So i'll try it. And we will see.

Comment: Nah, not working.I will play with boolean a bit and see what i can accomplish but i am not sure if it is the way. TY for afford anyways.

Comment: @derkarol You cannot call removeChild(_pokemon) if pokemon is already removed.  Do you recieve an error with my code?  If so, what?

Comment: Same on the same thing. It is something with memory. It ceeps it in memory somehow, i don't know yet. #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. But remember i got this error not on Main class but on pokemon clas during its movement path callculating/setting.Even though it was allready removed and becouse of it.